# NLog does not log correct method name for async methods

Tags: nlog

I am using NLog 4.4.6 and .Net 4.6.1

When I have an async method that does logging, the {callsite} that is logged is some bogus method name (i.e. fullyqualifiedclassname_d_20.MoveNext)

I've looked through the NLog issue list, and this is supposed to work starting in NLog 4.4

Does anyone else have this issue?

```
public async Task Handle(MyMessageType message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
   Log.Info("Starting...");
   await stateMachine.FireAsync(stateMachine.OnMyMessageType, context).ConfigureAwait(false);
   Log.Info("Finished.");
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it won't work well with `await`. The stacktrace is really different then

Comment: If you think this can be fixed (the name is in the stacktrace), please open an issue and post also the stacktrace (result of `new StackTrace().toString()`) https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new